# How to connect from PhoheGap Developer to VirtualBox MacOS Cordova test application?

Tags: ios, cordova, virtualbox

I'am trying to test some simple iOS application with Cordova. My MacOS is in VirtualBox and test it with `cordova emulate ios` command. From official docs I read, that possible to test application with PhoneGap Developer (https://itunes.apple.com/app/id843536693), but when your MacOS is a native OS (not virtual image).

Is there some method to connect PhoneGap Developer to test application executes from VirtualBox MacOS?

Comment: No, you have to have a mac.

Comment: @Joerg port forwarding?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you want to run a simulator. For port mappings I use Charles: https://www.charlesproxy.com

Comment: @Joerg As I understand to test my application (which is loaded by cordova simulator in VirtualBox MacOS) i must to set port forwarding in VirtualBox (cordova simulator port) and then connect to VirtualBox with PhoneGap Developer. Is it right?